# Dataframe style is not getting exported to excel

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, xlsxwriter, pandas-styles

I tried styling my dataframes

```
df.style\
    .applymap(add_color,\
             subset=[column names])\
    .format('{0:,.0f}',na_rep='-')
```

I tried to export this style after storing it to excel but non of the styling is applied. However, the styling is working in jupyter.

I have a df like this

[image]

I want it

[image]

Also how do you copy paste it as tables instead of images in stackoverflow?

I tried looking for a solution but all failed.

Comment: function for color:-

def add_color(x):
    if x<threshold:
        color='red'
    elif x>threshold:
        color='lightgreen'
        
    return f'background: {color}'



dataframe styling:-

df1=df1.style\
    .applymap(add_color,\
             subset=[column names])\
    .format('{0:,.0f}',na_rep='-')

df2=df2.style\
    .applymap(add_color,\
             subset=[column names])\
    .format('{0:,.0f}',na_rep='-')

export to excel:-
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sh1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sh2')

Comment: @Arul Raj Edit and add the code sample to your question. Please do not add additonal details , code samples or clarifications as comments unless its a short statement.

Comment: For pasting data in tables see this link [Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)